# "keyboard's key" visual formatting for keyboard shortcuts kind of cheat-sheet

Tags: formatting

Would it be possible to visually have the key in a "box". Similar to https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/1480108495/macos-keyboard-shortcuts-cheat-sheet or https://vfxstudy.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Fusion-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-Resolve-v1-724x1024.png  ??
Just a simple rounded box black and white would do.
I saw some topics related to cheatsheet [multi-colored cheat sheet for keyboard shortcuts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590198/multi-colored-cheat-sheet-for-keyboard-shortcuts) , but to me having the keys visually highlighted in a "box" is key ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach using the `menukeys` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}

\keys{\ctrl+C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with the `keystroke` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keystroke}

\begin{document}

\Ctrl +\keystroke{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your spacing in the `keystroke` example is off (due to the space before the `+` being ignored, but not after it).

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks!

Comment: Should the Ctrl and C be vertically centered as well, in the keystroke example?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis You can use `\raisebox` to move them up and down as you like